# How to create a captcha verification in delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, captcha

Exactly like what the title asks - i am wondering to now wether i can use a captcha verification into my signup form ( Using delphi 2010 )

Comment: You obviously need to generate the captcha on the server side. I strongly recommend not creating a captcha yourself, but look for ways to embed an existing one, such as recaptcha.

Comment: Is it a server side application (like a web app), or a client/server application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captcha it's just a graphic with some text on it. So, you can make an image, and output some
text on it. If you need more info, then you need to describe more fully
what it's about making a captcha that you don't understand.

Perhaps you may keep a list of all the possible words in a database table, and pass
the word's id number into your captcha function. This way you'll have a way
of knowing if the user typed in the correct word and make supplementary checks if you want.

Here you have how to draw a transparent text over an image:

[Writing Transparent Text on Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360476/writing-transparent-text-on-image)

and there are a lot of examples on the internet.

Or, you can use a component to do the work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Use an Image control and draw different elements to obtain the Captcha. 
You can draw some letters using code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.letrasAnguladas(c : string; angulo : integer; nextPos : Integer);
var
   logfont:TLogFont;
   font: Thandle;
begin
   LogFont.lfheight:=30;
   logfont.lfwidth:=10;
   logfont.lfweight:=900;

   LogFont.lfEscapement:=angulo;
   logfont.lfcharset:=1;
   logfont.lfoutprecision:=OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS;
   logfont.lfquality:= DEFAULT_QUALITY;
   logfont.lfpitchandfamily:= FF_SWISS;
   logfont.lfUnderline := 0;
   logfont.lfStrikeOut := 0;

   font:=createfontindirect(logfont);

   Selectobject(Image1.canvas.handle,font);

   SetTextColor(Image1.canvas.handle,rgb(0,180,0));
   SetBKmode(Image1.canvas.handle,transparent);

   Image1.canvas.textout(nextPos,Image1.Height div 3,c);
   SetTextColor(Image1.canvas.handle,rgb(Random(255),Random(255),Random(255)));
   deleteobject(font);
end;
```

You can use it like this:

```
   for vX := 1 to Length(strCaptcha) do
      letrasAnguladas(strCaptcha[vX],Random(600)+1,25*vX-15);
```

Finally, you can add some line to the captcha using code similar to this:

```
  for i := 0 to 15 do begin
    Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := Random(100000);
    Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(random(Image1.Width), random(Image1.Height));
    Image1.Canvas.LineTo(random(Image1.Width), random(Image1.Height));
  end;
```

Change parameters and try other to modify the result. 
You can obtain some images like this:

[image]

Regards.

Comment: This code works perfectly except a little bug: the line with TextOut and the one with SetTextColor must be inverted so that each letter is effectively drawn in a different color.

Answer (score 1):

Works with  the inverted lines in maXbox:

```
 procedure TForm1letrasAnguladas(c : string; angulo : integer; 
                                 nextPos : Integer; image1: TImage);
 var logfont:TLogFont;
     font: Thandle;
    //Image1: TImage;
    //form: TForm;
 begin

   LogFont.lfheight:=45;
   logfont.lfwidth:=10;
   logfont.lfweight:=900;

   LogFont.lfEscapement:=angulo;
   logfont.lfcharset:=1;
   logfont.lfoutprecision:=OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS;
   logfont.lfquality:= DEFAULT_QUALITY;
   logfont.lfpitchandfamily:= FF_SWISS;
   logfont.lfUnderline := 0;
   logfont.lfStrikeOut := 0;
   font:=createfontindirect(logfont);

   Selectobject(Image1.canvas.handle,font);
   SetTextColor(Image1.canvas.handle,rgb(0,180,0));
   SetBKmode(Image1.canvas.handle,TRansparent);
   SetTextColor(Image1.canvas.handle,rgb(Random(255),Random(255),Random(255)));
   Image1.canvas.textout(nextPos,Image1.Height div 3,c);
  //SetTextColor(Image1.canvas.handle,rgb(Random(255),Random(255),Random(255)));
  deleteobject(font);
end;

form1:= TForm.create(self);
image1:= TImage.create(self);
with form1 do begin
 setbounds(100,100, 300,250)
 show;
 with image1 do begin
   parent:= form1;
   setbounds(0,0,300,220)
   for it := 0 to 15 do begin
     Canvas.Pen.Color := Random(100000);
     Canvas.MoveTo(random(Width), random(Height));
     Canvas.LineTo(random(Width), random(Height));
   end;
  end;  
 end;
 

strCaptcha:= 'str-Captcha'
for vX := 1 to Length(strCaptcha) do
  TForm1letrasAnguladas(strCaptcha[vX],Random(600)+1,25*vX-15, image1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call the Google recaptcha api.